# Test class not getting full coverage?

Tags: unit-test

In my test class not getting full coverage, some methods are not covered.
Could you please some one help me how to get full coverage???
Test Class:

```
static testMethod void Expense(){                                
        Members__c objmember = new Members__c();
        objmember .User_Email__c = 'testrec';   
        objmember .Role__c   = 'member';        
        System.assertEquals('member', objmember .Role__c);
        insert objmember ;
        update objmember ;

        Subproject__c objsubproj = new Subproject__c();
        objsubproj .name = 'testname';            
        objsubproj .Description__c = 'sampdesc';
        objsubproj .Starts_date__c =  System.now().date();
        objsubproj .Ends_date__c =  System.now().date();    
        System.assertEquals('testname', objsubproj .name);
        insert objsubproj ;

        Project__c prj = new Project__c ();
        prj.Name='ITC';
        //prj.Plantype__c= pt.Id;
        prj.Ends_date__c = system.toDay().addDays(3);
        prj.Starts_date__c= system.toDay();
        prj.Status__c = 'In Progress';
        System.assertEquals('ITC', prj.name);         
        insert prj;

        test.startTest();
        ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters().put('id', objmember .id);
        ApexPages.StandardController sc = new ApexPages.standardController(objmember );
        ExpenseController expcont1 = new ExpenseController();   
        ExpenseController expcont = new ExpenseController(sc);     
        //expcont.Save();
        //expcont.cancel();
        //expcont.redirectToTemplate(); 
        test.stopTest();        
   }
 }
```

**Below Code is the apex class i'm not covered these methods in my test class**

Apex Class:

```
Public Pagereference Save(){
          member = new Members__c (); 
          if (Members__c.sObjectType.getDescribe().isUpdateable())
              {
           update member;
              }
           Pagereference PR = new Pagereference('/apex/ProjectDetails?id='+EncodingUtil.urlEncode(projectid,'UTF-8')+'&sfdc.override=1');
            return PR;

    }
    Public Pagereference cancel(){

        Pagereference PR = new Pagereference('/apex/SubProject?id='+EncodingUtil.urlEncode(projectid,'UTF-8')+'&sfdc.override=1');
        return PR;
       }
        public Members__c  templateInfo {get; set;}
}
```

Comment: Is it because you commented out expcont.Save(); and expcont.cancel(); ?

Comment: yes, but i remove comments i get update failed error : update member;

Comment: I remove comments on save and cancel methods and run test class i get below error.

Comment: System.DmlException: Update failed. First exception on row 0; first error: MISSING_ARGUMENT, Id not specified in an update call: []                                    update member;

Comment: This last problem you report is caused by the save method containing the bug that it creates a new Members__c (that therefore has no ID) and then updates it. Did you instead mean to insert it? Or should the ID passed into the controller class be being used?

Comment: yes, in the controller class in save method we create a new member..                    Below it shows.....................

Comment: Public Pagereference Save(){
          member = new Members__c (); 
          if (Members__c.sObjectType.getDescribe().isUpdateable())
              {
           update member;
              }
           Pagereference PR = new Pagereference('/apex/ProjectDetails?id='+EncodingUtil.urlEncode(projectid,'UTF-8')+'&sfdc.override=1');
            return PR;

Comment: Any one can help me how to get 75% coverage for above test class?